Is This Rust/Corrosion in Evaporator Drip Pan Typical?
While performing an inspection and servicing of HVAC system pre-summer, I noticed what I feel is a more-than-negligible amount of rust/corrosion in drip pan and at coils.  Pic attached.  So...should I be concerned, and if so, what actions should I take?
The system was installed in July 2016 (so about 8 years old), and my air handler and evaporator are in an open-air attic in north Texas, if any of that is important.



Adding pic of under-sink drain from condensate line:


Some rust is normal.  The seam above the bottom row of coils in the second picture looks worse than I would expect for 8 years.  The secondary pan, ideally, should remain dry.   So the question isn't so much if rust is normal, but why is there any water in the secondary?  You may have some freezing going on causing abnormal amounts of water and stress and resulting in all of this.

A little rust inside is fine, but you should never have water in the drip pan.  That looks like you’ve had a leaking air handler for years.  The drip pan is a failsafe to save your ceiling if the drain plugs or the internal pan leaks.  The alarm may need to be relocated if it doesn’t reach the low point.
So fix the drain or pan, alarm it properly, and move on.  The rust won’t get worse if it isn’t wet.  Also, open the condensate line valve and install a proper line with a trap.  The more I look at the condensate arrangement the less I like it, the pan drain needs to be separate from the regular drain since the pan protects from the drain line clogging.

Part of the servicing is cleaning coils and rinsing with water...I noted that it doesn't drain terribly well out of the pan into the overflow tube.  I don't feel that I have a dripping-into-pan issue, as in I think I would have noticed, since never when I've gone up to look around (replacing a filter, for instance) has there been water in the pan or pan even seemed wet.  But given your advice, I'll try and keep a closer eye on it when A/C has been running for an afternoon/evening.  Hopefully I don't melt or burst into flames while up there...

Also felt I should mention: valve was closed just to make sure it and drains were functioning as intended.  I took a picture before re-opening valve and walking away.  As to trap, that line runs down and into a Y junction before the trap under one of my bathroom sinks.  Do you feel that is an OK set-up/installation?

@AA040371 might be worth reaming out the drain pipe then.

@AA040371 I have never seen a condensate drain go into a plumbing system.  I feel like this must not be okay or I would have seen this before.

@TigerGuy: I've added a pic just so it is clear what I am talking about.  I am sure your experience is sound; this is Texas and house was built using code and practices from 25 years ago.  Note the plumbing fitting (or whatever) is seemingly deigned for this purpose.....I've no idea if it would still be allowed?

@AA040371 I did look up code and apparently it's okay to plumb to wastewater if the drain gives you an air gap.  you do still need a separate line for the pan drain - you have a single point of failure for both.  And again, the pan should stay dry.  Also can't tell if you have a trap on the discharge line.

@TigerGuy:  I really appreciate you taking the time for this.  re: dedicated line for pan drain, pic is not doing a good job displaying...do you see the drain fitting and PVC pipe just below (obscured) by black insulation tubing on condensate line?  It sorta looks like a wire is leading into it, but it isn't....that pan drain pipe leads straight out to a spot right above my door to my back patio...I test that line is clear/works every year as well, hence the water in the drain pan.  Is this what you are looking for?

@AA040371 yes, you should be able to see when the pan is draining.  I hope I've helped a little, that's the object here.

And with all the trips up into the attic I now understand that there is a condensation drip forms on the refrigerant line right where insulation stops and line enters evaporator, and drips right where the rust spot was worst on the left - hence the plastic cup to catch.  Assuming this happens whenever it is hot enough to keep system running more than usual and humidity is high (it's been at/above 80% for several days due to all the rain).  Not quite sure what's causing the drip on the right side yet, unless it is simply an over-abundance of water being pulled from the air by the system.

Fairly typical. They don't bother to use stainless steel (more expensive, harder to bend/cut) for the steel parts, just galvanized, and usually electroplated (thin) galvanizing (zinc coating over steel) rather than thicker and more expensive hot dip galvanizing, so when the zinc layer eventually corrodes away the steel begins to rust.
Also, exposed edges of cut sheets may rust sooner than that, as the steel core is exposed.
You could brush away any loose rust (using extreme care not to touch the refrigerant lines if choosing to work on the evaporator) and paint with "cold galvanizing" paint - mix that very well, as it works due to having zinc particles in it.
The pan is less risky to work on. The risk of damaging a refrigerant line .vs. the rate at which the evaporator is rusting may not fall in favor of touching that. If there's any long-term warranty that might also affect whether you want to mess with it, but that may not apply by now.

I had never heard of cold galvanizing paint, but of course that's what this site is for/about :--)  So, yeah, I may do some light brushing/sanding on pan and rinse, then maybe paint, but will leave the coils alone.  Thanks...
